# How can I define an isomorphism here?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $V$ be a variety in $A^n$(affine n-space with algebracally closed field k base) , $I=I(V) \subset k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n], P \in V $, and let $J$ be an ideal of $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ that contains $I$. Let $J'$ be the image of $J$ in $ \Gamma(V) $. Show that there is a natural homomorphism $\phi$ from $O_p(A^n)/JO_p(A^n)$ to  $O_p(V)/J'O_p(V)$, and that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. In particular, $O_p(A^n)/JO_p(A^n)$ is isomorphic to $O_p(V)$.

I'm looking up Fulton's algebraic curve. In this problem, how can I set a mapping $\phi$ to make it isomorphic? Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify the notation? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, Armando. $\Gamma (V)$ denotes $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] / I(V)$ and $I(V)$ is irreducible since $V$ is a variety. And $O_p(V)$ is the local ring of $V$ at $p$, that is, $O_p(V)=\{ F/G : F,G \in \Gamma(V) and G(p) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Hint: consider the natural projection $\pi:\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}})\to\mathcal{O}(V)$; passing first to localizations in $p$ and after to quotients, what happens it?

Comment: Could you give me some more hints? Thanks!